# Expo Go and widgets - Can they coexist?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, widget

I am trying to use Expo Go; however, there seems to be no way to create widgets and keep using the Expo Go app?

I installed react-native-android-widget which says that is compatible with expo; however, once I create a widget and use the package as a plugin the app gives the following error when running on Expo Go:

```
Uncaught Error:
The package 'react-native-android-widget' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure:

- Your rebuilt the app after installing the package
- You are not using Expo Go
```

So my question is, do I have to stop using expo go from now on? I mean, I have been using it a lot and the debugging process is so fast by just having my phone on the side as I code. How should I change my process? Should I stop using expo go, or is there a way to continue using it while developing widgets for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `react-native-android-widget` you will need to create an Expo Dev Client.

https://saleksovski.github.io/react-native-android-widget/docs/tutorial/register-widget-expo#build-dev-client

Using the Expo Dev Client you will have a similar experience as with Expo Go, except you can add additional native libraries (like `react-native-android-widget`).